# Key repeat on Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard

When you hold a key on the keyboard under Windows XP, the keyboard seems to send Key Down, Key Up repeatedly. However I am developing for a device where holding a key generates a "proper" key repeat, that is, lots of Key Down and then one Key Up when you release the button.

I want to get the same behaviour under Windows to get our emulator to work as on he device. Is there anyway to acheive this? Do I need to get another keyboard driver? Thanks!

Comment: That shouldn't happen. WM_KEYUP is sent once when the key is released, and always has a repeat count of one. Perhaps your keyboard is weird or broken.

Comment: Or maybe You are catching events with some weird technology that triggers them with the keypress event? Keypress event is supposed to be repeated AFAIK.

Comment: Youre right, something wrong in our API that translates the keys to Click on just KEYDOWN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in an internal API as stated in the comment